# ASP.NET Button does not raise postback

Tags: jquery, asp.net, postback

**My situation**:

I have a problem with an ASP.NET button, which does not raise a postback when I click the button.

I have a button, which has an ID "PurchaseBtn". When clicking this button, I open a Panel called "PurchaseDiv", using jQuery.

The button which doesn't work is the "PutInBasket" button. Nothing happens when I click the button, and certainly no postback.

I've tried adding a OnClientClick="return true;" , and then a postback happends - but no codebehind is run. Therefore that is not a solution as well.

**Code**

I have the following code:

```
    <asp:Button ID="PurchaseBtn" runat="server" Text="Køb" />
<asp:Panel ID="PurchaseDiv" runat="server" CssClass="Popup">
<asp:HyperLink id="PopupCloseLnk" runat="server" CssClass="popupClose">x</asp:HyperLink>  


    <h3>Køb <asp:Label ID="LinkTypeName" runat="server"></asp:Label></h3>
    <p>Ønsket URL:<br />
        <asp:TextBox ID="UrlBox" runat="server" Width="250"></asp:TextBox>
        <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="UrlReq" runat="server" ControlToValidate="UrlBox" Text="*" ForeColor="Red"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
    </p>

    <p>Antal:<br />
        <asp:Textbox ID="QuantityBox" runat="server"></asp:Textbox>
        <asp:NumericUpDownExtender ID="QuantityExtender" runat="server"
        Width="100"
        TargetControlID="QuantityBox"
        Minimum="1"
        Maximum="200">
    </asp:NumericUpDownExtender>
    </p>
    <br />
    <p>Anchor tekster<br />
        <asp:TextBox ID="AnchorTexts" runat="server" TextMode="MultiLine">
        </asp:TextBox>
        <asp:TextBoxWatermarkExtender ID="AnchorTextsExtender" runat="server" WatermarkCssClass="watermarked" 
        TargetControlID="AnchorTexts" WatermarkText="Ikke påkrævet at udfylde" />
    </p> 

    <asp:Button ID="PutInBasket" runat="server" Text="Put i kurv" 
        onclick="PutInBasket_Click" />

</asp:Panel>
<asp:Panel id="bgPopup" runat="server" CssClass="bgPopup"></asp:Panel>
```

And the following jQuery:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function loadPopup() {
        //loads popup only if it is disabled  
        if ($('#<%=bgPopup.ClientID %>').data("state") == 0) {
            $('#<%=bgPopup.ClientID %>').css({
                "opacity": "0.7"
            });
            $('#<%=bgPopup.ClientID %>').fadeIn("medium");
            $('#<%=PurchaseDiv.ClientID%>').fadeIn("medium");
            $('#<%=bgPopup.ClientID %>').data("state", 1);
        }
    }

    function disablePopup() {
        if ($('#<%=bgPopup.ClientID %>').data("state") == 1) {
            $('#<%=bgPopup.ClientID %>').fadeOut("medium");
            $('#<%=PurchaseDiv.ClientID %>').fadeOut("medium");
            $('#<%=bgPopup.ClientID %>').data("state", 0);
        }
    }

    function centerPopup() {
        var winw = $(window).width();
        var winh = $(window).height();
        var popw = $('#<%=PurchaseDiv.ClientID%>').width();
        var poph = $('#<%=PurchaseDiv.ClientID%>').height();
        $('#<%=PurchaseDiv.ClientID%>').css({
            "position": "absolute",
            "top": winh / 2 - poph / 2,
            "left": winw / 2 - popw / 2
        });
        //IE6  
        $('#<%=bgPopup.ClientID %>').css({
            "height": winh
        });
    }

    $(document).ready(function () {
        var mouse_is_inside = true;

        $('#<%=PurchaseDiv.ClientID%>').hover(function () {
            mouse_is_inside = true;
        }, function () {
            mouse_is_inside = false;
        });

        $("body").mouseup(function () {
            if (!mouse_is_inside) {
                disablePopup();
            } 
        });

        $('#<%=bgPopup.ClientID %>').data("state", 0);
        $('#<%=PurchaseBtn.ClientID%>').click(function () {
            centerPopup();
            loadPopup();
        });

        $('#<%=PopupCloseLnk.ClientID %>').click(function () {
            disablePopup();
        });

        $(document).keypress(function (e) {
            if (e.keyCode == 27) {
                disablePopup();
            }
        });
    });

    $(window).resize(function () {
        centerPopup();
    });  

</script>
```

**Codebehind for PutInBasket**

```
protected void PutInBasket_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    var purchase = BuildPurchase();

    if(SessionManager.Purchases = null)
    {
    SessionManager.Purchases = new Purchase();
    }

    SessionManager.Purchases.AddPurchase(purchase);

    RedirectManager.RedirectToShoppingBasket();}
```

***Markup in HTML***

```
 <body>

    <form method="post" action="Default.aspx" onsubmit="javascript:return WebForm_OnSubmit();" id="form1">

<div class="aspNetHidden">

<input type="hidden" name="ToolkitScriptManager1_HiddenField" id="ToolkitScriptManager1_HiddenField" value="" />

<input type="hidden" name="__EVENTTARGET" id="__EVENTTARGET" value="" />

<input type="hidden" name="__EVENTARGUMENT" id="__EVENTARGUMENT" value="" />

<input type="hidden" name="__VIEWSTATE" id="__VIEWSTATE" value="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" />

</div>



<script type="text/javascript">

//<![CDATA[

var theForm = document.forms['form1'];

if (!theForm) {

    theForm = document.form1;

}

function __doPostBack(eventTarget, eventArgument) {

    if (!theForm.onsubmit || (theForm.onsubmit() != false)) {

        theForm.__EVENTTARGET.value = eventTarget;

        theForm.__EVENTARGUMENT.value = eventArgument;

        theForm.submit();

    }

}

//]]>

</script>





<script src="/Client/WebResource.axd?d=OQImHOjbC8T9DkQAEsUir2SbTKmI8ZHSylTzW2Dc_v2PQCtNyS3HT4PJHErgeJx_VIraTiSecUhyJJm6dR8vatqP9g2Jc9yVKn3Q2ZgQiXU1&amp;t=634685062757536216" type="text/javascript"></script>





<script src="/Client/ScriptResource.axd?d=wBt9eolujUDT1pwJVXfdkbPt3q6kho05pcKqWgTyNHdCTBOV8kYqK-XubOHF3qVWllTVqvuXXPnc41-lbrsFIHVDLKwJaNX7FkZ6ir8UIWzkCnSjfN0j1OMJiUgdaTA6xM6LXQF8MVlGpJHoPSvyxzKcilhfqsLP0c-fl2Lt0Mc1&amp;t=150492e7" type="text/javascript"></script>

<script src="/Client/ScriptResource.axd?d=UP06sTpweppdnIadbdu8iZGs1AZaASdPaGRzQUw527ewVZ7zBazaEOYbnh_jf7YtCQMLSB2Hvr25yeSR5oCk-0zjwGmQ19sQWp6ex8TA4DnvWtZYtv58zaC8COurXpj3OrICAaySLoXeOt0r12dnpQ2&amp;t=fffffffffd88dfc4" type="text/javascript"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">

//<![CDATA[

if (typeof(Sys) === 'undefined') throw new Error('ASP.NET Ajax client-side framework failed to load.');

//]]>

</script>



<script src="/Client/ScriptResource.axd?d=vFgiOpDr8tKXR2y_94kZYrOfpgLUdhZXjzsbRg0Z4ZyFIo0hRl2M_hrQvnzhD4-5xANDsYczXpx031bvwW78vpfjOADpPKmQJYO45cCutF_q9BnxFi6v1fdC4snZUAlirCG8fNtXsSXIc2nxdEeIEQ2&amp;t=fffffffffd88dfc4" type="text/javascript"></script>

<script src="/Client/Default.aspx?_TSM_HiddenField_=ToolkitScriptManager1_HiddenField&amp;_TSM_CombinedScripts_=%3b%3bAjaxControlToolkit%2c+Version%3d4.1.60623.0%2c+Culture%3dneutral%2c+PublicKeyToken%3d28f01b0e84b6d53e%3aen-US%3a187c1d17-2715-476f-9eeb-4fd46e2849ea%3ade1feab2%3af9cec9bc%3aee910bbe%3a35576c48" type="text/javascript"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">

//<![CDATA[

function WebForm_OnSubmit() {

null;if (typeof(ValidatorOnSubmit) == "function" && ValidatorOnSubmit() == false) return false;

return true;

}

//]]>

</script>



<div class="aspNetHidden">



    <input type="hidden" name="__EVENTVALIDATION" id="__EVENTVALIDATION" value="/wEWBwKRoIbQCQLNv7y8AQL3ypGNDwLD/ouZAwKcyMzCBgKB+6+CBQL7o4C5BYHZ9ukNCXioJ4HgOg0byK4OWNHAc/xaAvgFOzmITJSc" />

</div>

    <script type="text/javascript">

//<![CDATA[

Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager._initialize('ctl00$ToolkitScriptManager1', 'form1', [], [], [], 90, 'ctl00');

//]]>

</script>





    <div class="WrapperContent">


        <div class="Maincontent">

            <table>

                <tr>

                    <td class="MainContentTd">



            <table id="ContentPlaceHolder1_LinksOverview1_ProductView_tblProducts" cellpadding="2" cellspacing="10">





        <tr id="ContentPlaceHolder1_LinksOverview1_ProductView_ctrl0_productRow">


        <td id="ContentPlaceHolder1_LinksOverview1_ProductView_ctrl0_Td1_0" style="vertical-align:top; text-align:left; height:100%; padding:8px; width:205px;">

        <div id="sub">

        <div id="category">

            <br />

                <div id="ContentPlaceHolder1_LinksOverview1_ProductView_ctrl0_PutProductHereDiv_0">



<script type="text/javascript">

    $(document).ready(function () {

        $('#ContentPlaceHolder1_LinksOverview1_ProductView_ctrl0_ctl00_0_questionMark_0').mouseover(function (e) {

            $('#ContentPlaceHolder1_LinksOverview1_ProductView_ctrl0_ctl00_0_HintDiv_0').show();

        });



        $('#ContentPlaceHolder1_LinksOverview1_ProductView_ctrl0_ctl00_0_questionMark_0').mouseleave(function (e) {

            $('#ContentPlaceHolder1_LinksOverview1_ProductView_ctrl0_ctl00_0_HintDiv_0').hide();

        });

    });

</script>

<h3>

    <span id="ContentPlaceHolder1_LinksOverview1_ProductView_ctrl0_ctl00_0_LinkTypeDescription_0">Blogkommentar</span>

    <span id="ContentPlaceHolder1_LinksOverview1_ProductView_ctrl0_ctl00_0_questionMark_0" class="questionMarkLayout">(?)</span></h3>

<table>

    <tr>

        <td>

            <span id="ContentPlaceHolder1_LinksOverview1_ProductView_ctrl0_ctl00_0_PriceLbl_0">29,00 DKK</span>

        </td>

        <td>

<script type="text/javascript">

    function loadPopup() {

        //loads popup only if it is disabled  

        if ($('#ContentPlaceHolder1_LinksOverview1_ProductView_ctrl0_ctl00_0_PurchaseButton1_0_bgPopup_0').data("state") == 0) {

            $('#ContentPlaceHolder1_LinksOverview1_ProductView_ctrl0_ctl00_0_PurchaseButton1_0_bgPopup_0').css({

                "opacity": "0.7"

            });

            $('#ContentPlaceHolder1_LinksOverview1_ProductView_ctrl0_ctl00_0_PurchaseButton1_0_bgPopup_0').fadeIn("medium");

            $('#ContentPlaceHolder1_LinksOverview1_ProductView_ctrl0_ctl00_0_PurchaseButton1_0_PurchaseDiv_0').fadeIn("medium");

            $('#ContentPlaceHolder1_LinksOverview1_ProductView_ctrl0_ctl00_0_PurchaseButton1_0_bgPopup_0').data("state", 1);

        }

    }



    function disablePopup() {

        if ($('#ContentPlaceHolder1_LinksOverview1_ProductView_ctrl0_ctl00_0_PurchaseButton1_0_bgPopup_0').data("state") == 1) {

            $('#ContentPlaceHolder1_LinksOverview1_ProductView_ctrl0_ctl00_0_PurchaseButton1_0_bgPopup_0').fadeOut("medium");

            $('#ContentPlaceHolder1_LinksOverview1_ProductView_ctrl0_ctl00_0_PurchaseButton1_0_PurchaseDiv_0').fadeOut("medium");

            $('#ContentPlaceHolder1_LinksOverview1_ProductView_ctrl0_ctl00_0_PurchaseButton1_0_bgPopup_0').data("state", 0);

        }

    }



    function centerPopup() {

        var winw = $(window).width();

        var winh = $(window).height();

        var popw = $('#ContentPlaceHolder1_LinksOverview1_ProductView_ctrl0_ctl00_0_PurchaseButton1_0_PurchaseDiv_0').width();

        var poph = $('#ContentPlaceHolder1_LinksOverview1_ProductView_ctrl0_ctl00_0_PurchaseButton1_0_PurchaseDiv_0').height();

        $('#ContentPlaceHolder1_LinksOverview1_ProductView_ctrl0_ctl00_0_PurchaseButton1_0_PurchaseDiv_0').css({

            "position": "absolute",

            "top": winh / 2 - poph / 2,

            "left": winw / 2 - popw / 2

        });

        //IE6  

        $('#ContentPlaceHolder1_LinksOverview1_ProductView_ctrl0_ctl00_0_PurchaseButton1_0_bgPopup_0').css({

            "height": winh

        });

    }



    $(document).ready(function () {

        var mouse_is_inside = true;



        $('#ContentPlaceHolder1_LinksOverview1_ProductView_ctrl0_ctl00_0_PurchaseButton1_0_PurchaseDiv_0').hover(function () {

            mouse_is_inside = true;

        }, function () {

            mouse_is_inside = false;

        });



        $("body").mouseup(function () {

            if (!mouse_is_inside) {

                disablePopup();

            } 

        });



        $('#ContentPlaceHolder1_LinksOverview1_ProductView_ctrl0_ctl00_0_PurchaseButton1_0_bgPopup_0').data("state", 0);

        $('#ContentPlaceHolder1_LinksOverview1_ProductView_ctrl0_ctl00_0_PurchaseButton1_0_PurchaseBtn_0').click(function () {

            centerPopup();

            loadPopup();

        });



        $('#ContentPlaceHolder1_LinksOverview1_ProductView_ctrl0_ctl00_0_PurchaseButton1_0_PopupCloseLnk_0').click(function () {

            disablePopup();

        });



        $(document).keypress(function (e) {

            if (e.keyCode == 27) {

                disablePopup();

            }

        });

    });



    $(window).resize(function () {

        centerPopup();

    });  



</script>



<input type="submit" name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$LinksOverview1$ProductView$ctrl0$ctl01$ctl00$PurchaseButton1$PurchaseBtn" value="Køb" onclick="javascript:WebForm_DoPostBackWithOptions(new WebForm_PostBackOptions(&quot;ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$LinksOverview1$ProductView$ctrl0$ctl01$ctl00$PurchaseButton1$PurchaseBtn&quot;, &quot;&quot;, true, &quot;&quot;, &quot;&quot;, false, false))" id="ContentPlaceHolder1_LinksOverview1_ProductView_ctrl0_ctl00_0_PurchaseButton1_0_PurchaseBtn_0" />



<div id="ContentPlaceHolder1_LinksOverview1_ProductView_ctrl0_ctl00_0_PurchaseButton1_0_PurchaseDiv_0" class="Popup">



<a id="ContentPlaceHolder1_LinksOverview1_ProductView_ctrl0_ctl00_0_PurchaseButton1_0_PopupCloseLnk_0" class="popupClose">x</a>  





    <h3>Køb <span id="ContentPlaceHolder1_LinksOverview1_ProductView_ctrl0_ctl00_0_PurchaseButton1_0_LinkTypeName_0">Blogkommentar</span></h3>

    <p>Ønsket URL:<br />

        <input name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$LinksOverview1$ProductView$ctrl0$ctl01$ctl00$PurchaseButton1$UrlBox" type="text" id="ContentPlaceHolder1_LinksOverview1_ProductView_ctrl0_ctl00_0_PurchaseButton1_0_UrlBox_0" style="width:250px;" />

        <span id="ContentPlaceHolder1_LinksOverview1_ProductView_ctrl0_ctl00_0_PurchaseButton1_0_UrlReq_0" style="color:Red;visibility:hidden;">*</span>

    </p>



    <p>Antal:<br />

        <input name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$LinksOverview1$ProductView$ctrl0$ctl01$ctl00$PurchaseButton1$QuantityBox" type="text" id="ContentPlaceHolder1_LinksOverview1_ProductView_ctrl0_ctl00_0_PurchaseButton1_0_QuantityBox_0" />



    </p>

    <br />

    <p>Anchor tekster<br />

        <textarea name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$LinksOverview1$ProductView$ctrl0$ctl01$ctl00$PurchaseButton1$AnchorTexts" rows="2" cols="20" id="ContentPlaceHolder1_LinksOverview1_ProductView_ctrl0_ctl00_0_PurchaseButton1_0_AnchorTexts_0">

</textarea>

        <input type="hidden" name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$LinksOverview1$ProductView$ctrl0$ctl01$ctl00$PurchaseButton1$AnchorTextsExtender_ClientState" id="ContentPlaceHolder1_LinksOverview1_ProductView_ctrl0_ctl00_0_PurchaseButton1_0_AnchorTextsExtender_ClientState_0" />

    </p> 



    <input type="submit" name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$LinksOverview1$ProductView$ctrl0$ctl01$ctl00$PurchaseButton1$PutInBasket" value="Put i kurv" id="ContentPlaceHolder1_LinksOverview1_ProductView_ctrl0_ctl00_0_PurchaseButton1_0_PutInBasket_0" />





                </div>

<div id="ContentPlaceHolder1_LinksOverview1_ProductView_ctrl0_ctl00_0_PurchaseButton1_0_bgPopup_0" class="bgPopup">



                </div>   



        </td>

    </tr>

</table>

<br />

<div id="ContentPlaceHolder1_LinksOverview1_ProductView_ctrl0_ctl00_0_HintDiv_0" class="HintDiv">



    <span id="ContentPlaceHolder1_LinksOverview1_ProductView_ctrl0_ctl00_0_DescriptionLbl_0"><h3>Blogkommentar</h3>beskrivelse af blog</span>



                </div>



            </div>

            <br />

            </div>



        </td>







        </tr>



</table>








                    </td>

                    <td class="RightContentTd">

                        <br />







                        <br />





                    </td>

                </tr>

            </table>




</div>

        </div>

    </div>



<script type="text/javascript">

//<![CDATA[

var Page_Validators =  new Array(document.getElementById("ContentPlaceHolder1_LinksOverview1_ProductView_ctrl0_ctl00_0_PurchaseButton1_0_UrlReq_0"));

//]]>

</script>



<script type="text/javascript">

//<![CDATA[

var ContentPlaceHolder1_LinksOverview1_ProductView_ctrl0_ctl00_0_PurchaseButton1_0_UrlReq_0 = document.all ? document.all["ContentPlaceHolder1_LinksOverview1_ProductView_ctrl0_ctl00_0_PurchaseButton1_0_UrlReq_0"] : document.getElementById("ContentPlaceHolder1_LinksOverview1_ProductView_ctrl0_ctl00_0_PurchaseButton1_0_UrlReq_0");

ContentPlaceHolder1_LinksOverview1_ProductView_ctrl0_ctl00_0_PurchaseButton1_0_UrlReq_0.controltovalidate = "ContentPlaceHolder1_LinksOverview1_ProductView_ctrl0_ctl00_0_PurchaseButton1_0_UrlBox_0";

ContentPlaceHolder1_LinksOverview1_ProductView_ctrl0_ctl00_0_PurchaseButton1_0_UrlReq_0.evaluationfunction = "RequiredFieldValidatorEvaluateIsValid";

ContentPlaceHolder1_LinksOverview1_ProductView_ctrl0_ctl00_0_PurchaseButton1_0_UrlReq_0.initialvalue = "";

//]]>

</script>





<script type="text/javascript">

//<![CDATA[

(function() {var fn = function() {$get("ToolkitScriptManager1_HiddenField").value = '';Sys.Application.remove_init(fn);};Sys.Application.add_init(fn);})();

var Page_ValidationActive = false;

if (typeof(ValidatorOnLoad) == "function") {

    ValidatorOnLoad();

}



function ValidatorOnSubmit() {

    if (Page_ValidationActive) {

        return ValidatorCommonOnSubmit();

    }

    else {

        return true;

    }

}



document.getElementById('ContentPlaceHolder1_LinksOverview1_ProductView_ctrl0_ctl00_0_PurchaseButton1_0_UrlReq_0').dispose = function() {

    Array.remove(Page_Validators, document.getElementById('ContentPlaceHolder1_LinksOverview1_ProductView_ctrl0_ctl00_0_PurchaseButton1_0_UrlReq_0'));

}

Sys.Application.add_init(function() {

    $create(Sys.Extended.UI.NumericUpDownBehavior, {"Maximum":200,"Minimum":1,"RefValues":"","ServiceDownMethod":"","ServiceDownPath":"/Client/Default.aspx","ServiceUpMethod":"","Tag":"","TargetButtonDownID":"","TargetButtonUpID":"","Width":100,"id":"ContentPlaceHolder1_LinksOverview1_ProductView_ctrl0_ctl00_0_PurchaseButton1_0_QuantityExtender_0"}, null, null, $get("ContentPlaceHolder1_LinksOverview1_ProductView_ctrl0_ctl00_0_PurchaseButton1_0_QuantityBox_0"));

});

Sys.Application.add_init(function() {

    $create(Sys.Extended.UI.TextBoxWatermarkBehavior, {"ClientStateFieldID":"ContentPlaceHolder1_LinksOverview1_ProductView_ctrl0_ctl00_0_PurchaseButton1_0_AnchorTextsExtender_ClientState_0","WatermarkCssClass":"watermarked","WatermarkText":"Ikke påkrævet at udfylde","id":"ContentPlaceHolder1_LinksOverview1_ProductView_ctrl0_ctl00_0_PurchaseButton1_0_AnchorTextsExtender_0"}, null, null, $get("ContentPlaceHolder1_LinksOverview1_ProductView_ctrl0_ctl00_0_PurchaseButton1_0_AnchorTexts_0"));

});

//]]>

</script>

</form>

</body>
```

Comment: Did you check for any javascript errors?

Comment: Yep - nothing comes in Firebug at least

Comment: Do you have any validation controls on page?

Comment: Yes a requiredfieldvalidator. I just tried removing it. Then my window made a full postback - but no code run in codebehind. Same result as having a "return true" on OnClientClick on the button

Comment: Can you please show us the mark up for the form? (`<form ...>`)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your issue is on this function

```
function WebForm_OnSubmit() {

null;if (typeof(ValidatorOnSubmit) == "function" && ValidatorOnSubmit() == false) 
     return false;

return true;

}
```

This function return false and not let the form submit. Why is this return false ? I do not know, check your code and fix this part of the validation.

Comment: I used this to track down the problem.. 

The problem?
I had my LoadControls() method inside a if(!Page.IsPostback) , and the postback never happend.

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Do you have an onclick even in the code behind for PutInBasket_Click? Since you said no code behind is run; should be something like..

```
protected void PutInBasket_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // Put code here
}
```

Comment: Can you post that method please?

Comment: Try setting on the button CausesValidation = false.

Comment: Same effect as OnClientClick="return true;"

Answer (score 0):

I think it is just that your "if" statement needs a double-equal sign.

```
if(SessionManager.Purchases == null)
```

Comment: Looking again, this is probably not the main problem if you had a breakpoint at the very first line and are certain that no code executed.

Comment: :) Yeah, that's not the issue - accidently removed the two equal signs when I psoted